# How to combine 2 integers in order to get 1?

Tags: c

I searched about this but I didn't find a clear answer for this problem in C language.

Imagine that I have an `int a = 123` and another `int b = 456`.

How do I combine them in order to get `combine(a, b) == 123456`?

Comment: Please define the problem more clearly; a single example leaves some questions open. For example, I don't know what `combine(12, 34)`, or `combine(1234, 5678)`, or `combine(5, -3)` should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can multiply `a` by 10-to-the-power-of-N, where N is the number of digits in `b`, then add that number to `b`.

Less efficiently, you can convert both to strings, concatenate them, then parse that string into an integer.

In either case, there is a possibility of integer overflow.

If `b` is allowed to be negative, you will have to further define the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

First find the number of digits in "b"
This can be done as follows:

```
int find_num_digits(int b)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (b > 0)
 {
   b = b/10;
   i++;
 }
return i;
}
```

Then do:
c = a*10^find_num_digits(b) + b;

"c" is the result.
You will have to make sure that "c" doesn't go out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
int combine(int a, int b) {
  return 1000*a + b;
}
```

More generically:

```
int combine(int a, int b) {
  if (b==0) return a;
  return combine(a, b/10)*10+ b%10;
}
```

Comment: this will not work for any `a` smaller then 100 nad bigger than 1000.

Comment: It wasn't specified that the numbers could be from different ranges. Anyway, I added more generic solution.