# How to combine integers in c#

Tags: c#

Im looking for a way to combine my integers together.
I got 3 integers i want to make one from them.

All the integers are holding a time currency wich looks a little like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
int timeHours = date.Hour;
```

I got the Hours, Minutes and Seconds and want to combine so they would look like this:

```
Hour : Minutes : Seconds
```

How can i combine the integers together to do that.

**Note: I've looked on the internet but i could not get the information i was looking for.**

**This is what i looked at:**

[Combine two integers to create a unique number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248501/combine-two-integers-to-create-a-unique-number)

[How to combine 2 integers in order to get 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530219/how-to-combine-2-integers-in-order-to-get-1)

Comment: Why do you want to combine them in a single integer, rather than having a type to represent "time of day" or something similar? What do you mean by "they would look like this"? An integer doesn't "look" like three values separated by colons...

Comment: As what - a string? or some other type?

Comment: What's your exact requirement, this can be achieved using string concat. Anyway an integer cannot have ":" in it, so you need string

Comment: I think your asking a way to get the current time am i right?

Comment: Nobody knows what OP wants but all answer it.

Comment: I think i need to go for the option Giorgi Nakeuri gave. Did not think that would work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i want to show the current time for in my console application

Comment: Here is my guess, he just wants this: `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes thats what i want but i didnt know you could do it like that

Comment: @TimSchmelter Wouldn't be better to use as `H:m:s` format? Sounds like (not sure!) OP wants to get single digits _without_ leading zero? Like `5` instead of `05` or something :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: i don't know what OP wants, i would prefer `10:07:46` to `10:7:46`

Comment: @SonerGönül I prefer 10:07:12 instead of 10:7:12

Comment: This is why it's important to provide context when you ask a question - you weren't really interested in combining integers, you were interested in converting a date/time to a string.

Comment: There are countless duplicates, you just have to search with the right terms. Then you find questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341886/get-date-time-hours-and-minutes-with-leading-zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast to string with `format` function for example:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeHours, timeMinutes, timeSeconds);
```

Just to be complete:

**format `HH:mm:ss`:**

```
string result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timeHours, timeMinutes, timeSeconds);

string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

**format `H:m:s`:**

```
string result = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", timeHours, timeMinutes, timeSeconds);

string result = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:m:s");
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining these integers will generate a `string`, not an another integer. You can easily format your `DateTime` with [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
var str = DateTime.Now.ToString("H':'m':'s"); // eg: 11:0:2
```

If you wanna get your hour, minute and second part *with* leading zeros for single digits, you can use `HH:mm:ss` format instead.

```
var str = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss"); // eg: 11:00:02
```

Comment: I believe you don't need quotes here - just `H:m:s` will do the job

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It depends on what OP's `CurrentCulture` is. `:` character (which is [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) has a special meaning as _replace me with current culture or supplied culture time separator_. That means if OP's current culture has a different time separator than `:`, output string will be different format. I know there are only 5 framework culture that has `.` as a time separator, _still_ there is a chance.

Comment: you are very globalize-able :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Believe me, I wish I couldn't :)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Now` already contains all information you need, **date** and **time**. All you need to do is [format this information](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways to pack two (or many) integers into one based
on their ranges, e.g.

```
  int i1 = 123;
  int i2 = 456;
  // two 32-bit integers into 64-bit one
  long result = (((long) i1) << 32) | i2;
```

In your particular case

```
  int hours = 5;
  int minutes = 10;
  int seconds = 59;

  int combined = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
```

reverse:

```
  int combined = 12345;

  int seconds = combined % 60;
  int minutes = (combined / 60) % 60;
  int hours = combined / 3600;
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri In fairness, the question can not be solved exactly as asked - "I got 3 integers **i want to make one from them**." - This solves that, and is what I'd assumed was wanted too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below code i think it's useful

```
       var date = DateTime.Now;
        var result = date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute + ":" + date.Second;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I've tried that, in this case they is it as a calculation

Comment: So they will summ up the values

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using the base 10 number system is to just

```
var number = hours * 10000 + minutes * 100 + seconds
```

this returns a number like 150936 for 15:09:36

To convert back:

```
seconds = number % 100
minutes = (number / 100) % 100
hours = number / 10000
```

Note that this is obviously not the most efficient approach, but simple